# AngularJS $http calling infinitely

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, http, mean-stack

Can someone explain why is the $http request sending infinite number of requests to the server?
In my application, this code sends infinite requests to the server

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module("GrahamsSocksProducts", ["ngCookies"]);
    app.controller("ProductsController", ["$controller", "$http", "$cookies", function($controller, $http, $cookies){
.
.
.
this.setCookie = function(){
        username = "Some random guy"
        alert(45)

        $http({
            method : "GET",
            url : "http://_____________",
            params : { username : username }
        }).then(function(){
            //do something
        })
    }
```

However, when I remove the http request, only a single request is passed to the server, like this :

```
.
.    
.
this.setCookie = function(){
        username = "Some random guy"
        alert(45)
}
.
.
.
```

HTML :

```
<div ng-app="GrahamsSocksProducts">
        <div ng-controller="ProductsController as products">
        {{ products.setCookie() }}
            <div class="row">
                <div ng-repeat="product in products.products">
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img ng-src="{{products.getImageTag(product)}}">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4 class="pull-right">${{ product.price }}</h4>
                                <h4>
                                    <a href="#"> {{ product.name }}</a>
                                </h4>
                                <p>{{ product.description }}</a>.</p>
                                </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ratings">
                        <p class="pull-right">{{ product.ratings }} / 5</p>
                        <p>
                                <span ng-class="products.getStarColor(product.ratings, 1)" ng-click="product.ratings=1"></span>
                                <span ng-class="products.getStarColor(product.ratings, 2)" ng-click="product.ratings=2"></span>
                                <span ng-class="products.getStarColor(product.ratings, 3)" ng-click="product.ratings=3"></span>
                                <span ng-class="products.getStarColor(product.ratings, 4)" ng-click="product.ratings=4"></span>
                                <span ng-class="products.getStarColor(product.ratings, 5)" ng-click="product.ratings=5"></span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="products.addToCart(product)">Add to Cart</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-default">Checkout</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="container">                 
                        <div class="jumbotron">
                            <ul class="list-group"ng-repeat="cartProduct in products.getCartNameAndQuantity()">
                                <li class="list-group-item">{{ cartProduct.name }}  ({{ cartProduct.quantity }})</li>
                            </ul>
                            Cart products price : {{ products.getCartPrice() }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have read other questions such as this:
[Infinite loop when trying to make Angularjs display a promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25231413/infinite-loop-when-trying-to-make-angularjs-display-a-promise)
They have answered about how AngularJS allows two-way data-binding but in this case, when the $http code is removed, the request is sent once, otherwise infinite times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression {{ products.setCookie() }} is run every time the digest loop is run which is A LOT.  Every time the page changes, click, events, etc.  I'm not sure why you have this expression on the view itself but you'll need to put it elsewhere

Comment: If OP wants to run this when `ProductsController` gets instantiated, should put that in the body of the controller definition.

Comment: Yes, that's a much better place for it to be.  It will only be run when the controller gets instantiated

Comment: You should also remove this function call from the view and bind to a value that gets set in the controller:   <img ng-src="{{products.getImageTag(product)}}">

Comment: didn't know about the digest loop before; I should have mentioned "newbie in AngularJS". Thanks

Comment: what better way to learn about it than to have it make your app explode :)